# Axios Ajax, returning undefined from call to API

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I've got an issue whereby my ajax call is returning undefined when I'm trying to drill further down into the data.

Please see the API documentation below.

https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api.php

So I'm using the ID method.

https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=11007

Here is my constructor function where the call is made...

```
export default class Recipe {
    constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    async getRecipe() {
        try {
            const res = await axios(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=` + this.id);
            this.title = res.data.drinks.strDrink;
            this.image = res.data.drinks.strDrinkThumb;
            this.measure = res.data.drinks.strMeasure1;
            this.ingredients = res.data.drinks.strIngredient1;
            this.method = res.data.drinks.strInstructions;
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where I'm testing the output...

```
const r = new Recipe(11007);
r.getRecipe();
console.log(r);
```

I wondered if perhaps I've exceeded the API call limit as I'm using their test API. But I can still make calls successfully elsewhere.

What is strange is if for example I made the same call to the API but just had res.data.drinks, it will return the full details for the cocktail of the ID passed into the function.

But when I try to drill down further, it just returns undefined.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you aren't awaiting calling `getReciepe`

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` the return of you asynchronous call as you declared an `async` function. Alternatively, you could also use the standard Promise API

```
someAsyncFunction().then(result => console.log(result))
                   .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But even awaiting the call still returns undefined. See following.. `async function Test () {
    const r = new Recipe(11007);
    await r.getRecipe();
      console.log(r);
}`

Comment: returns `Recipe {id: 11007, title: undefined, image: undefined, measure: undefined, ingredients: undefined, …}
id: 11007
title: undefined
image: undefined
measure: undefined
ingredients: undefined
method: undefined`